# Java app 'steals' stdin from cmd.exe console

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java app as a spawned child process under Windows 7. 
The command I am using is in the lines of: `java -cp ...list of libs...`
The problem is that once the application loads, it doesn't have its own stdin stream but try to uses its parent's stdin, which results in that commands can not be passed to it.
Are there any parameters of 'java.exe' that can twick this behavior, so the child process will have its own stdin?
Thanks

**Update:**
Sorry I am not a java programmer but could this happen because of this line in the java app I am running:

```
this(new IO(System.in, System.out, System.err), STANDARD_INPUT_PROMPT, STANDARD_RESULT_PROMPT);
```

If so, what is an adequate substitute to `System.in`?

Comment: How are you spawning the JVM?

Comment: What is the `IO` class?  I've never heard of it.

Comment: @TofuBeer Not sure what you mean, I am using the "java.exe" with the specified params to run the application.

Comment: @MikeClark I thought its a standard java class, but thanks for bringing it up, I will look into it

Comment: "am trying to run a java app as a spawned child process under Windows 7" - how are you doing that step?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just start a new command prompt that spawns the child process?  I don't program much for windows environments much but I got the following to work:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k start cmd /k echo hello");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

If you replaced echo with your subprocess program and hello with necessary arguments then you should be all set to receive stdin.  In other words do:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /k start cmd /k java -cp ...list of libs...");
```

There might be a much prettier method of doing this by the way.

Comment: Interesting idea, had hopes that it will work but for some reason the java app still takes over the cmd.exe (even second one) stdin. Is there like a 'master' stdin stream in java?